# Hibernate allowing null even when we have specified not-null true in hbm

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, hibernate

We have a column in a table whose hbm enrty is like

```
<property name="test" type="java.lang.String" update="true"
            insert="true" column="test" length="60" not-null="true"
             />
```

However, while insertion it allow us to insert null value in test column.

**Hiberate version : 3.5.4-Final**

Please let me know if we are missing anything for restrict null value.

Comment: Can you take a look at the databáse description? As i know These Information are only used when hibernate will create the tables. it is not a nullcheck at runtime.

Comment: At database level our system doesn't have any restriction.

Comment: Maybe you need to configure a validation for the field. Look at https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-xmlconfiguration.html#validator-xmlconfiguration